# How do I get the menu program to restart after completing a selection?

Tags: java

My program is stuck in an infinite loop after a selection is made and completed. It needs to restart and go through the menu options again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Add");
    System.out.println("2. Subtract");
    System.out.println("3. Multiply");
    System.out.println("4. Divide");
    System.out.println("5. Generate a random number");
    System.out.println("6. Quit\n");

    System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    int count = 0;

    while (choice < 1 || choice > 6){
        count ++;
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, " +choice+ " is not a valid option.\n");
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add");
        System.out.println("2. Subtract");
        System.out.println("3. Multiply");
        System.out.println("4. Divide");
        System.out.println("5. Generate a random number");
        System.out.println("6. Quit\n");
        System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 6){
            continue;
        }
        else if (count == 2){
            System.out.println("Please try again later.");
            System.exit(0);
            return;
        }
      }


    do
    {
        switch (choice) 
        {
            case 1: choice = 1;

                System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
                int firstAdd = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("What is the second number? ");
                int secondAdd = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Answer: " +(firstAdd + secondAdd));

                break;

            case 2: choice = 2;

                System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
                int firstSub = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("What is the second nubmer? ");
                int secondSub = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Answer: " +(firstSub - secondSub));

                break;

            case 3: choice = 3;

                System.out.print("What is the first number?" );
                int firstMult = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("What is the second number? ");
                int secondMult = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Answer: " +(firstMult * secondMult));

                break;

            case 4: choice = 4; 

                System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
                double firstDiv = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("What is the second number? ");
                double secondDiv = input.nextInt();

                    while (secondDiv == 0){
                        System.out.println("I'm sorry, you can't divide by zero.");
                        break;}
                    {

                    System.out.println("Answer: " +(firstDiv / secondDiv));
                    break;
                    }


            case 5: choice = 5;

                System.out.println(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

                break;

            case 6: choice = 6;

                System.out.println("Goodbye!");

                System.exit(0);
                return;
        }

    }while (choice >=1 && choice <= 6);



}
```

I've tried a few different options that I found in my book, but they seem to cause more errors in other areas. I don't know if there is a different statement than "break;" to use to restart the menu because this is my first time using cases.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose everything after the scanner instantiation in a while loop.

Specifically,

```
while (true) {
    // your code
    if (choice == 6)
        break;
}
```

FIXED: Also remove the `do {} while()` loop. Your loop is infinite because "choice" does not change in the loop.

Comment: The code compiles without any issues. The only problem I'm having is once you make a selection and finish it, it starts the same selection over again. For example, if you do choice 1, you enter the two numbers for addition, your answer is given, then it asks for two numbers to be entered again for the addition choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was just trying to over-complicate things apparently.

Comment: Remember to approve the answer!